# Count product selled in a day for each type of product

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a problem in my query.
Imagine I have 10 product (product1, product2, product3), and today (08/16/2021), I'm selling 15 "product1, 2 product2 and 5 product3. I need to now every day how many product I sold, and be able to get all of them for each day.

Tell me if my class are good enough, and what query or code can I use.

```
@Entity(tableName = "stock_products")
data class StockProducts (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    val timestamp: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "productName")
    val orderList: List<ProductInfo>
)
```

Comment: Please remove the android-jetpack-compose tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database should be designed to cover your needs.
If you don't want to add an extra column with only the day, you can calculate the timestamp of today at 00:00 and make the query "Select orderList where timestamp > $todayTimestamp"

Also, the timestamp shouldn't be a String.